# How to pull all Wikipedia article titles as autocomplete tags for my site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wikipedia

I think it would be good to incorporate tags/tokens with an autocomplete feature. I will use Wikipedia article titles to dynamically build the list of possible tokens (thus enabling autocomplete.) I am using Rails 4 and Ruby but any pointers would be great, I don't quite know where to begin with this.

The purpose is so that users do not just make up anything as tag (tagging themselves as expletives+nouns, for example.) And if it became possible to keep this master list updated (which is what I meant as "dynamically", it would be great. But even manually updated is ok.

I so far assume that part of it would include a web crawler that only searches :title fields on wikipedia. I am using Postgres as my DB.

Once I have a list, I can use something like the jquery token fields gem or chosen gem, as I learned from Railscasts. In those two examples, there was a list that enabled the autocomplete for tokens. I want that exact thing, but to get them from Wikipedia titles. 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised

This will be done in Rails 4 and I am using Postgres. I will probably be on Heroku as well.

Comment: Probably useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

Answer (score 0):

You could use the API to fetch titles beginning with whatever the user typed so far like this:    [api.php?action=query&list=allpages&apfrom=Bav&aplimit=5](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&apfrom=Bav&aplimit=5) (assuming english Wikipedia here). Add `&format=json` or `&format=xml`.

Many of the suggestions, however, would be quite meaningless in other contexts than Wikipedia, e.g. titles with disambiguation suffixes: [Bac](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&apfrom=Bac&aplimit=7). And most of the [expletives](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&apfrom=Fuck&aplimit=450) and nouns you can think of *will* be there, so it won't do a good job at sorting them out, either.

If you plan to use the function on a heavily visited site, you should probably [download](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download) and host the list of titles yourself, not to put extra load on the Wikimedia servers.